# Seven Deadly Sins Manga to Anime question

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Which chapter of seven deadly sins is season 2 episode 3?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is an exact way to pinpoint this, because the manga often is not correlated with anime episodes, and the anime is often abbreviated as to not become a 10,000 episode Naruto. I would say, however that it is around chapter 108-120.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the previous answer, it's found [here](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_3). It comprises of **Chapters 113-116**.

Wikia pages of anime usually includes episodes and the chapters that they were based on.